# How to generate a 3D world similar to SceneKit using RealityKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I am looking for general guidance and resources as to how I can render a 3D scene in my app. I can procedurally generate whats in the scene. Ex. Make a grid, identify which objects go where, etc. But I want to know how to actually implement this into scene. with a world, where users can observe the scene (move camera, zoom in an out). I also want to animate the scene. At some point, I would also like the scene to be observable in real-life, picture Monument Valley except your looking at it in the real world.

From what I can see, SceneKit seems to capable of accomplishing this in a non-AR context. However, it also seems to be no longer supported by apple. I am not sure where/how to render custom assets and not just basic spheres or shapes using RealityKit (i.e. this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02icMrf5Idc&t=1s). I am looking for any guidance or resources to accomplish this.

A useful start would be some resources explaining how I can render a scene (without AR) using custom assets in Xcode (not playgrounds, please).